# how to get yesterday's date in qt?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, qt4

I need to display yesterday's (preivious one of current date) using QT. I got current date using QDate . how can i reduce a date from current one ?  can anyone have any ideas ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the documentation:

http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qdate.html#addDays

```
QDate yesterday = today.addDays(-1);
```